# What is the difference between cv::stereo::StereoMatcher::compute and cv::StereoMatcher::compute in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV 4.3, there are two function members with the same name and functionality in different namespaces and with different inheritance trees: `cv::stereo::StereoMatcher::compute` and `cv::StereoMatcher::compute`. What is the difference between them?

Note: I posted this question to Answers OpenCV a week ago, but it didn't get any answers.

Comment: Did you check the code? Is it possible that one is an alias to the other?

Comment: It's not an alias. It looks like a change between v3 and v4 of OpenCV with no corresponding update of documentation. I will raise this issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

`cv::StereoMatcher::compute` is defined in a main module `calib3d`. `cv::stereo::StereoMatcher::compute` is defined in an extra module `stereo` from https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib repository, which has limited support. The functionality seems to be very similar, with more algorithms in official `cv::StereoMatcher::compute` version.